# What are the key differences between hosting with Netlify, Google Cloud, Bluehost, and GoDaddy?

Tags: web, cloud, hosting, web-development-server

I wanted to host my website but I am getting lit bit confuse on what should I use a traditional hosting from Bluehost, GoDaddy or should I use service like Netlify or Google cloud. I want build my site and want to add big things as I go on. Please suggest and help me out

I want to know what service should I use to host my website.